# HTML5 appcache causing jquery getJSON to return error

Tags: jquery, html, html5-appcache

I'm having an issue when trying to use getJSON on a link while the current page is cached through appcache. The browser is online which I have checked with `navigator.onLine` and I'm pretty certain my internet is connected. I've tried with both AppCache and without and it seems that there is only an error when I'm using AppCache which leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong or you're unable to send json requests when the page is loaded with appcache?

Here is the result of the json request (See code below) with and without appcache turned on:

With AppCache (Failed):
[image]

Without AppCache (Yay it works):
[image]

**NOTE:** *The request is cross-domain, although I do have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set on the destination.*

## My Code

***Service.appcache***

```
CACHE MANIFEST
plugins/bootstrap-switch.min.css
plugins/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css
plugins/bootstrap-datepicker.css
plugins/jquery.min.js
plugins/bootstrap-switch.min.js
plugins/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js
plugins/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js
plugins/Dexie.min.js
plugins/jSignature.min.js
plugins/bootstrap.min.css
plugins/select2.min.css
plugins/select2.full.min.js
fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2


SETTINGS:
prefer-online
```

***index.php***

```
<html manifest="/service.appcache"> 
....
$( document ).on( 'click', '#getdbdata', function () 
{
    if(navigator.onLine == true) 
    {
        $.getJSON( "http://example.com/getdata?apikey="+apikey, function( data ) 
        {
            console.log(data);
            alert( "Database has been updated!" );
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert( "Could not update the database at this time!" );
        })

    }
});
....
</html>
```

I don't know too much about appcache, so I was wondering why the request is not going through. Any help would be nice, thanks!

Comment: try to add `NETWORK: *` section to your CACHE MANIFEST

Comment: @Maxali I cannot believe I forgot to do that, it seemed to fix my issue. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it as the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `NETWORK: *` section to your CACHE MANIFEST.